# Variable possibly undefined when used inside another function (Typescript “error TS2532)

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

So here we go, trying Typescript. I got this function for view for my automatic global component registration in Vue. To be honest I have no idea on how this would translate in Typescript. It's the `fileName` inside `camelCase(fileName.split('/'))` function.

```
import upperFirst from 'lodash/upperFirst'
import camelCase from 'lodash/camelCase'


// other code

requireComponent.keys().forEach(fileName => {
  const componentConfig = requireComponent(fileName)

  // here
  const componentName = upperFirst(
    camelCase(
      fileName
        .split('/')
        .pop()
        .replace(/\.\w+$/, '')
    )
  )

  Vue.component(
    componentName,
    componentConfig.default || componentConfig
  )
})
```

Typescript error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pop` returns `string | undefined`, so you can either save that in a variable to check for `undefined` or be bold and claim that it will always be defined using `!`:

```
  fileName
    .split('/')
    .pop()!
    .replace(/\.\w+$/, '')
```

(It is not really that bold because splitting an empty string will always return at least an array containing the empty string, so pop should resolve to an element.)

---

Variable check would look something like this:

```
const last = fileName
    .split('/')
    .pop();
if (last == undefined)
    throw Error("This has never happened before.")

// Compiler now will 'know' that last is a string.
camelCase(last.replace(/\.\w+$/, ''));
```

Comment: How would I go about the variable check you mention?

Comment: Does this error happen because of eslint or is this Typescript specific? I was under the impression that all js would work the same in ts.